# Make selected <a> bold when clicked inside nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive, ng-class

I want to make selected choice as *bold*. Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/vd5hE0I8ke1bnGjUNN2W?p=preview) which I have created. I thought of putting `ng-class='className'` and then setting

`$scope.className=selection`

inside directive controller, but it got applied to all the elements. How to make clicked as bold and then when other option is selected, I want that previous selected to choice to drop that class and newly make newly selected option as bold.

```
.selection{
  font-weight: bold;
 }
```

I found [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287845/adding-a-css-class-to-element-on-ng-click) but for this i would have to create another directive and also I would have to handle the scenario where prev element to drop class and make newly selected element *bold*

Comment: Normally you would have two separate directives, one for managing the list and one for managing the list element. Element directive can then require the list directive and notify it when it is clicked. Then it is up to the list controller to notify currently selected element it is not selected any more and hence maintain any other consistency between your elements. Unfortunately it will be tricky to put it within an answer as your angular directive structure seems to be far off at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ng-class` like:

```
<a ng-class="{'selection': $parent.val == group.name}" ng-click="selectedVal(group.name)">{{group.name}} ({{group.count}})</a>
```

Updated Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/gyEAGo6Mb77DK7yFo8td?p=preview. Note that it works only for the top level elements.

Comment: but what abt other level ? :(

Comment: You'll have to figure it out by yourself since you have a starting point now.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Pal ! http://plnkr.co/edit/euMAMsw2Y3e7iUlULgqh?p=preview . I didnt had to get into `$parent` when I moved `$scope.selectedVal` to `mainCtrl` controller.